# Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}' when passing data

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the following error when passing data

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Here is my code

*Service*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SidePanelAccordianService {
  private _openStateBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject({});
  public openState$ = this._openStateBehaviorSubject.asObservable();

  public setOpenState(data: { id: string, state: boolean }) {
    this._openStateBehaviorSubject.next(data);
  }
}
```

*TS*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SidePanelAccordianData } from './side-panel-accordian.model';
import { SidePanelAccordianService } from './side-panel-accordian.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-panel-accordian',
  templateUrl: './side-panel-accordian.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-panel-accordian.component.scss']
})
export class SidePanelAccordianComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: SidePanelAccordianData;
  panelOpenState;

  constructor(private accordianStateService: SidePanelAccordianService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  stateValue() {
    this.data.panelOpenState = !this.data.panelOpenState;
    this.accordianStateService.setOpenState({ id: this.data.id, state: this.data.panelOpenState });
  }

}
```

*Model*

```
export class SidePanelAccordianData {
  public id?: string = '';
  public title: string = '';
  public panelOpenState: boolean;
  public expanded: boolean;

  constructor(args) {
    this.id = args.id;
    this.title = args.title;
    this.panelOpenState = args.panelOpenState;
    this.expanded = args.expanded;
  }
}
```

*HTML*

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel (id)="data.id" (opened)="data.panelOpenState === true" (closed)="data.panelOpenState === false" [expanded]="data.expanded" (click)="stateValue()">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{ data?.title }}
            </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

*Component where error is coming*

```
this.accordianStateService.openState$.subscribe(data => {
  if (data.id === 'firstAccordionId') {
    this.firstDriverExpanded = true;
  } else if (data.id === 'secondAccordionId') {
    this.secondDriverExpanded = false;
  } else if (data.id === 'secondAccordionId') {
    this.thirdDriverExpanded = false;
  }
});
```

If I `console.log(data)` then I get `{}`. How can I set the value in the object before subscribing?

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can copy paste your code in our IDEs and only see the error that you are trying to fix

Comment: The type of the observable is inferred from the initial value, `{}`, which indeed _doesn't_ have an `id` (or `state`) property. _Is_ that an appropriate value? For that matter, why a _behaviour_ subject - does a starting value really make sense? Either way, why not be explicit about what it should be an observable _of_ by passing the generic parameter?

Comment: In `private _openStateBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject({});` line you just set the starting value to `{}`. Either use [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/subject) instead of [`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) to bypass default value, or specify value according to your needs.

Comment: I will update question with more code to give context

Comment: Apparently you expect it to be a `Subject<{ id: string, state: boolean }>`, so why don't you _tell the compiler that_ so it can help you provide appropriate values, rather than forcing it to try to guess based on an empty object?

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface SidePanelAccordianData {
  id: string;
  title?: string;
  panelOpenState: boolean;
  expanded?: boolean;
}

 private _openStateBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<SidePanelAccordianData  | undefined>(undefined);
```

or

```
  private _openStateSubject = new Subject<SidePanelAccordianData>();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to configure your `_openStateBehaviorSubject`  as following:

```
private _openStateBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<{ id: string; state: boolean }>({} as { id: string; state: boolean });
```

This will specify the generic type of the BehaviorSubject. If you don't pass it, the generic type will be just `{}` as the default value, and this is the cause of your error.

Comment: @skydev what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Actually, your answer only resolves typing issue. But the issue with console.log is not a typing issue. it's a value issue. I guess it solves only half the issue then.